# Background в css?

Tags: css

[image]есть картинка большая,как ее посавить фоном на весь body?

а как сделать такой прозрачный фон?если ставлю opacity 0.8 то и все элементы становятся полупрозрачными(текст,картинки)а мне надо чтобы только фон становился полупрозрачным?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

полупрозрачный фон

```
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

/*Изображение*/

```
body{
 background: url('ВАША КАРТИНКА') no-repeat center top;
 background-size: cover;
}    

/*полупрозрачный белый фон*/
.conteiner{
 width: 1000px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}
```

Пример

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: url('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/GaoBu5S1ct7Ge2-tFgDY-YcUHX3rKyVV_5j6DoxbrzFZZHnTIEreqigcXFDVW5y94j4=h900') no-repeat center top;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px 15px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: это для body поставить?

Comment: надо не background поставить,надо чтобы он был полупрозрачным

Answer (score 1):

```
background-image:url(img/bg.jpg);
```

Answer (score 1):

На CSS3:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  background-size: cover;

  /* то что ниже – для устаревающих браузеров. Про IE отдельная тема */
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Другие варианты и подробности на англ. [на css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/).

Comment: а как сделать полупрозрачный фон?

Answer (score 1):

Прозрачность фона вам доступна только через альфа-канал. Т.е. если это картинка, то это должен быть .png с прозрачностью. Если это цвет, то он должен быть задан через `background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.5); /*полупрозрачный белый*/`
Если вы примените `opacity`, то свойство унаследуется дочерними элементами и все они сделаются полупрозрачными, что вы и наблюдали.

Answer (score -1):

Используйте `img` тег и только его делайте прозрачным. Или просто `div` отдельно засуньте в `body`. `opacity` наследуется.